# Cannot call Action method from UrlHelper on ASP.NET MVC 5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, urlhelper

I am trying to create unit tests for my ASP.NET MVC 5.1 app.

I want to verify the outgoing URL by using the UrlHelper.Action() method.
I can do that with ASP.NET MVC 4, but cannot with ASP.NET MVC 5.1.

There is an exception when call the Action() method:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Please help me a solution!
Thanks

Comment: I can find out a solution from this link https://github.com/AnthonySteele/MvcRouteTester

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. In my case, the `NotImplementedException` was coming from `HttpContextBase.GetService`.

The following code solved the problem:

```
public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(serviceType);
}
```